# Coded UI Test in wpf datagrid doesn't recognize cells and rows when row style is applied

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, wpfdatagrid, coded-ui-tests

In WPF Datagrid, if row style is used, it does not detect the grid rows. If I remove the row style, it detects the cell and rows properly.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="c_dataGrid" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
      RowStyle="{StaticResource rowStyle}">
   <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="{Binding Id}"/>
    </Style>
   </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>  
</DataGrid>

<Style x:Key="rowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>    
</Style>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "detect"?

Comment: it doesn't recognize the datagrid row. It just says "Last action on list item was not recorded because the control does not have any good identification property."

Comment: coded ui testing is the holy grail. i don't think we are there yet however. The "Last action on list item was not recorded because the control does not have any good identification property." error message is enough to drive good devs mad.

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark here...
Does it make any difference if you apply the BasedOn property?

```
<Style 
    x:Key="rowStyle" 
    TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>    
</Style>
```